# Group is indecomposible but homomorphic image is not

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

> A nontrivial homomorphic image of an indecomposable group need not be indecomposable.

A group $G$ is indecomposable if $G \neq \{ e\}$ and G is not the (internal) direct product of two of its proper subgroups.

Let $f$ be a homomorphism such that it is non trivial an $G$ be an indecomposible group. I have to find a homomorphism after finding a indecomposible group. Every Simple group  is indecomposible, $\mathbb{Z}$ , $\mathbb{Z}_{p^n}$ and $S_n$ are indecomposible.

But I am unable to find a example  of homomorphism to prove that $f(P)$ is  not indecomposible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider the quotient map $\Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z/6 \cong \Bbb Z/2 \oplus \Bbb Z/3$

Comment: @Lucas What homomorphism are you considering?

Comment: @No-one the homomorphism $\Bbb Z\to \Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z, n \mapsto n + 6 \Bbb Z$